# Using Amazon S3 SDK to backup and restore iPhone data

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3, backup, restore

I have an Amazon S3 account and have downloaded the AWSiOSSDK framework/SDK pack.  The example works fine.  I can "List Buckets" and upload sample data.

I want to use S3 to backup user data and then provide the opportunity to download the same backup to restore the data as and when needed.

I thought it would be easy to identify the methods/classes to do this, but I am struggling.  I have looked through the documentation but it is overwhelming (for such a "straight forward" requirement).  I cannot find any online tutorials either.  I tried stripping out the relevant code & frameworks from Amazon's example, but stopped after hours of trying to get anything to work.

Does anyone point me to a tutorial (or provide sample code) showing how to use the Amazon SDK in XCode?  This is the first time I have tried online backup on iPhone, so please excuse if this seems simplistic.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To download:

```
s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];              
S3GetObjectRequest *request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"YOURKEY" withBucket:@"YOURBUCKET"];
S3GetObjectResponse *response = [s3Client getObject:request];
```

response.body is an NSData with the the download

To upload, S3PutObjectRequest works much the same way. You can specify either a filename or NSData.

```
s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];              
S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"YOURKEY" withBucket:@"YOURBUCKET"];
request.data = ...
S3PutObjectResponse *response = [s3Client putObject:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David.  Really appreciated. A couple of issues though.  I copied in AWSiOSSDK.framework, but I presume I have to import it into the header?  When I add #import AWSiOSSDK/S3/AmazonS3Client.h it seems to prevent any NSLog messages. Very odd.  Needless to say my upload is not working, but I cannot seem to debug.  Here is the code:

header

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h
#import AWSiOSSDK/S3/AmazonS3Client.h

#define ACCESS_KEY                   @""
#define SECRET_KEY                   @""

@interface S3_Try2ViewController : UIViewController {

AmazonS3Client *s3Client;

S3PutObjectRequest *putObjectRequest;
S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse;

S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest;
S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse;

}

-(IBAction) S3Upload;
-(IBAction) S3Download;


 @end
```

main

```
NSLog(@"Start upload");

NSString *bucketName = @"bucketName";
NSString *keyName    = @"asyncTestFile";
NSString *filename   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"txt"];

NSLog(@"filename %@",filename);

s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
putObjectRequest = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:keyName inBucket:bucketName];

NSLog(@"alloc finished");

putObjectRequest.filename = filename;

NSLog(@"Uploading");

putObjectResponse = [s3Client putObject:putObjectRequest];

NSLog(@"Finished?");
```

Comment: Have you linked the framework into your project in addition to importing the header in your ViewController? The AWS library does NOT disable NSLog for me.  Also ACCESS_KEY and SCRET_KEY given the proper values? Also, try this instead of putObjectRequest.filename to make sure it is not an issue with the filename: putObjectRequest.data =  [@"Sample uplodad text." dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: Curiouser & curiouser.  I had linked in the framework, so that wasn't the problem.  I logged onto Amazon, and there was my test file in the S3 bucket!  Trouble is, I am still getting no NSLog output at all!  So it works, but somehow disables NSLog messages to the console.  Hmmm.  Thanks for all your help :)